# kvm with paravirtualization support

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am preparing to verify KVM with paravirtualization support(mainly for networking).

Does mentioning  driver name as vhost is enough to make it run in paravirtualization mode ?

I have all options relevant to paravirtualization enabled as part of kernel configuration.

Do I need to insmod any other module apart from kvm.ko and kvm_intel.ko ?

Also, do I need to mention any kernel parameters as part of loading these modules(kvm.ko kvm-intel.ko) ?

qemu-system-x86_64 version 1.4.2

Thanks.

Referring this link :
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Virtio
It seems no special drivers is needed at host side.
<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtio_net is kvm's equivalent of paravirtualization for networking. You might get even better results, especially in terms of latency, if you use SRIOV or VMFEX, but you need special hardware for that.

Comment: To add further, You need to virio_net module loaded in Guest (Or have it compiled as part of kernel). <model type='virtio'/> needs to be mentioned as part of network section in XML file. You should obviously see better performance with paravirtualization

Comment: @kumar virtio_net is in every modern kernel, since 2.6.18. The question was about the host side modules to enable virtio_net - and indeed there are none required

Comment: << virtio_net is in every modern kernel, since 2.6.18.. You may be right here,I am mentioning here about a custom distribution.